# Matlab/Octave write Laplacian filter without image package functions

Tags: matlab, image-processing, octave

My task is to apply an laplacian filter to an image without using the functions from the image package like imfilter or fspecial. Here is my code so far and I think I only need a workaround for the imfilter and the imadjust functions:

```
clc;
close all;
a = im2double(imread('343a.tif')); 
lap = [-1 -1 -1; -1 8 -1; -1 -1 -1]; 
resp = imfilter(a, lap, 'conv'); 


minR = min(resp(:));
maxR = max(resp(:));
resp = (resp - minR) / (maxR - minR);


sharpened = a + resp;

minA = min(sharpened(:));
maxA = max(sharpened(:));
sharpened = (sharpened - minA) / (maxA - minA);

sharpened = imadjust(sharpened, [60/255 200/255], [0 1]);

figure; 
subplot(1,3,1);imshow(a); title('Original image');
subplot(1,3,2);imshow(resp); title('Laplacian filtered image');
subplot(1,3,3);imshow(sharpened); title('Sharpened image');
```

Would be very thankful for help :)

Comment: The first little bit, after your call to `imfilter`, is the Laplacian. All the rest you don't need. Look for the MATLAB function `conv2`.

Comment: if I use conv2(a,lap,"same") the image is nearly black and not gray as it is supposed to be...am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: you're displaying wrong. `imshow(resp,[])`